# Accessing input type="text" current value dynamically using jstl

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, jstl

I have the following  code of an input  text fetching value from a dropdown.I want to fetach the current value from input to match with map.key for my work.How to go about it

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="input-group">                                            
    <input type="Text" ID="datebox6" Class="form-control" value=10001 name="uid"></input>
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <b>Select Store</b><br>
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu6" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu6">
      <c:forEach var="Employee_id" items="${obj.dataEmp}">
        <li>
          <a>${Employee_id}</a>
        </li>
      </c:forEach>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">
  <b>
    <h5>Employee ID:</h5>
  </b>
  <c:out value="${param.uid}" />
  <c:forEach var="map" items="${obj.dataEmployee}" varStatus="status">
    <c:if test="${map.key==10002}">
    ${map.key}<br>
    Age:            
    ${map.value[1]}
    </c:if>
  </c:forEach>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a fundamental misunderstanding here: Your JSP using JSTL runs **on the server**, before the HTML is sent to the client's browser. The input has a "current value" only later, on the client's browser, long after your server-side code has stopped running.

If you want to make the page update dynamically using client-side information, you'll need to use a client-side technology (JavaScript combined with the DOM, directly or indirectly through a library like jQuery and/or a templating engine like Handlebars and/or an MVVM or MVC library/framework like ReactJS, Knockout, RivetsJS, etc.).

If you want to *refresh* the page with information from the client, you'll need to have a form post back to a JSP which receives the information as parameters and then generates a new page to send back to the browser.

Comment: this jsp I am using in a Spring MVC application and am also using javascript in this .Can you help me with how I can do the needful using these or Controller

Comment: @Raaj: To ask a question about doing things client-side, show the HTML that goes to the client (not the JSP/JSTL that creates it) and your JavaScript code working with it. That's not what this question is.

Comment: PFB the script with which I am  using to send data to Controller 
  var drop = { 
          
          empid1 :empid,
          
  
  }
  $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "new",
         data: drop,
         success: function (result) {
             // do something.
             //out.print("done");
         },
         error: function (result) {
             // do something.
         },
         
       
       });

Comment: Java Controller :--  @RequestMapping(value= "/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String home2(@ModelAttribute("empid1")String empid1,BindingResult result,Model model) throws ScriptException,ScriptException, IOException, ServletException {
  
  model.addAttribute("empidp", empid1);
  
  
  System.out.println("Empid in IC1: "+empid1 );

  
   return "/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp";
 }